# Power Circuit for outdoor mounted shutters

Tags: gfci

Is a GFCI required for an electric shutter installed outside under the soffit?
If the answer is yes can an AFCI be used in stead of the GFCI?

Comment: Yes, and no. Wet location needs Gfci or DFCI's

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the GFCI breaker for the outside locations (Wet).

AFCI is a different animal altogether.

Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter is specifically designed for ground faults to protect in damp locations where there is a current path such as a person between ground and hot.

Arc Fault Circuit Interrupter - is specifically designed to protect against arcing - where perhaps the outlet is so old and worn the current actually arcs across the power outlet to the plug. You might notice these will trip if you plug a vacuum into an outlet whereby the ON switch of the vacuum is in the ON position prior to plugging the device in to the wall receptacle - you will see that arc .. an AFCI will trip in this instance.